# Angular cli adding css and extra html in app.component.html

Tags: angular, command-line-interface

When using the Angular cli to create a new app, I  use

```
ng new myapp
```

and I would get a default app.component.html page with only a few lines with the css in the corresponding .css file.  Now it creates a much more elaborate .html page with about 275 lines of css in the html page.  It did create the .css file, but there's nothing in it.  I did install Angular Essentials extension, but removed it.  No effect.  I also tried to be specific using

```
ng new --inline-style false --inline-template false
```

also with no difference.

How can I fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you want to put css in the html? That's  it how angular works

Comment: I don't!  On new generation, the cli is putting the <style> tag inside the .html page.  I don't want that, I wan't to know how to make it generate properly - and with the old page with only 3 links if possible.  Now I get 500 lines of code.